# lp_solve starting basis

Tags: linear-programming

I'm working with some fairly large LP problems in R and running into very slow computation times. I'm using the 'lp_solve' solver R wrapper ( through lpSolve and lpSolveAPI packages ), and found the option to setup an advanced basis through lpSolveAPI.

Given the nature of my problem, I have a decent first guess at the solution, but before I go through the process of coding up a dynamic method to generating that first guess, I was wondering if anyone had any information on how the lp_solve software chooses a starting basis for the solve.

If it's approach is logical ( considering my knowledge of the system ), it may be that I don't need to code up that initial approximation.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the documentation of lpsolve's [set_basis](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/set_basis.htm):

> The default initial basis is bascolumn[x] = -x.

This means that every variable is at its lower bound. As far as I know this is the standard for the Simplex method with bounded variables, and thus will also apply to other solvers.